# .htaccess - works only with index.php/ not with /

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I have an test project in sub directory (G:/wamp/www/test) which has only **index.php** and **.htaccess**

I tried to make friendly urls by adding RewriteRule to .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/*$ index.php
```

This worked on all other projects but it is not working on this one. When I want to access an URL like this:

**`http://localhost/test/TESTING_URL`** I am getting default **404 Not Found** page. However, if I go like this: **`http://localhost/test/index.php/TESTING_URL`** - it works.

Apache error log is giving me the following error:

```
File does not exist: G:/wamp/www/test/TESTING_URL
```

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /test/

DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/*$ index.php
```

Make sure that this .htaccess file is in the directory `test` and that there aren't any conflicting rewrite rules in any .htaccess file at a higher level.

Otherwise the only difference is the addition of the RewriteBase line.

Comment: Still the same thing happens

Comment: I'm sorry, I realize now that you are in a subdirectory, the rewritebase should refer to that subdirectory. Additional comments added in the answer body.

Comment: Well, you see, I have moved .htaccess file from subdir to root dir (www) and it works good but I also tried removing it from root and adding your code into subdir, it doesn't work.